# Dijkstra algorithm alternatives - shortest path in graph, bus routes

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

i am using slightly modified Dijkstra algorithm in my app but it`s quite slow and i know there have to be a lot better approach. My input data are bus stops with specified travel times between each other ( ~ 400 nodes and ~ 800 paths, max. result depth = 4 (max 4 bus changes or nothing).

Input data (bus routes) :

```
bus_id | location-from | location-to | travel-time | calendar_switch_for_today
XX | A | B | 12 | 1
XX | B | C | 25 | 1
YY | C | D | 5  | 1
ZZ | A | D | 15 | 0

dijkstraResolve(A,D, '2012-10-10') -> (XX,A,B,12),(XX,B,C,25),(YY,C,D,5) 
=> one bus change, 3 bus stops to final destination
* A->D cant be used as calendar switch is OFF
```

As you can imagine, in more complicated graphs where e.g. main city(node) does have 170 connections to different cities is Dijkstra slower (~ more then 5 seconds) because compute all neighbours first one by one as it`s not "trying" to reach target destination by some other way...

Could you recommend me any other algorithm which could fit well ?

I was looking on :

- http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/bellmanford.html (is it faster ?)
- http://jboost.sourceforge.net/examples.html (i do not see
  straightforward example here...)

Would be great to have (just optional things) : 
- option to prefer minimal number of bus changes or minimal time
- option to look on alternatives way (if travel time is similar)

Thank you for tips

Comment: What makes you know there has to be a lot better approach?

Comment: Why not use the A* algorithm? http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm It achieves better performance by using heuristics.

Comment: @hakre : because there is a lot of better approach e.g. in TOP30 cities 80% of all bus changes occurs, or algorithm shouldn`t approach routes which goes back to original location ... I will look on A* thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  It's a variant of Djikstra's which uses a heuristic to speed up the search.  Under certain reasonable assumptions, A* is the fastest optimal algorithm.  Just make sure to always [break ties towards the endpoint](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#breaking-ties).

There are also variants of A* which can provide near-optimal paths in much shorter time.  See for example [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/how-does-dwarf-fortress-keep-track-of-so-many-entities-without-losing-performanc/32831#32831) and [here](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_CN03.pdf).

---

[Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-ford) *(as suggested in your question)* tends to be slower than either Djikstra's or A* - it is primarily used when there are negative edge-weights, which there are not here.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe A* algorithm? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm

Maybe contraction hierarchies? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies.

Contraction hierarchies are implemented by the very nice, very fast Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM):

http://project-osrm.org/

and by OpenTripPlanner:

http://opentripplanner.com/

A* is implemented by a number of routing systems. Just do a search with Google.

OpenTripPlanner is a multi-modal routing system and, as long as I can see, should be very similar to your project.

Comment: OpenTripPlanner a bit overhead for this specific case but it`s good to know it exists, maybe we will use it in the future if it brings benefits to us

Answer (score 0):

The [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) would be great for this; it achieves better performance by using heuristics.

Here is a simple tutorial to get you started: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)